# Encrypt Digit C++

Tags: c++, encryption, decimal

So I am trying to encrypt a four digit integer by adding seven to the digit then dividing the whole digit by ten.  In my program I am taking each single digit separately and then I need to divide the whole digit by ten. How can I combine all the separate int into one four digit number?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Define all variables needed
    int a,b,c,d,enc,ext;

    //Print dialog and input each single digit for the four number digit
    cout << "Enter Your First Digit:" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter Your Second Digit:" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Enter Your Third Digit:" << endl;
    cin >> c;
    cout << "Enter Your Fourth Digit:" << endl;
    cin >> d;
    //Add seven to each digit
    a += 7;
    b += 7;
    c += 7;
    d += 7;

    a /= 10;
    b /= 10;
    c /= 10;
    d /= 10;

    cout << "Your encrpyted digits:" << c << d << a << b <<endl;

    cout << "Enter 1 to exit:" <<endl;
    cin >> ext;

    if (ext = 1) {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

As you probably noticed I am dividing each number separately. I need to do them together. Then I am also creating a decrypting which I will get me back to the original number in a separate program.

Comment: `if (ext == 1)`. You need to use `==` operator but not `=` operator. `=` is for assignment and not for logical comparisons. The question is bit unclear. Could you explain what would be range of input you would be taking for a,b,c,d ?

Comment: What do you mean by "divide them together"?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag accordingly.

Comment: Make one or two examples of input-output

Comment: This is **not** encryption. It's not reversible.

Comment: Probably you really want to take **modulo** 10, not divide by 10. Division by 10 is irreversible... `(x + 7) % 10` instead is a bijection on the numbers [0..9].

Comment: This is an exercise out of my book for school. It says to replace each digit with the result of adding seven. Then getting the remainder after dividing by ten. Then swapping the first digit with the third then the second with the fourth? Am I not doign this correctly?

Comment: remainder after dividing by ten is what these people say modulo! :P :D

Comment: You know what the **remainder** is?

Comment: 12 % 10 gives 2, hope ure looking for this!

Comment: I wasn't sure what modulo was! So that is what I need to use? Not division? I know what the remainder is just wasn't sure how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the individual digits into one four-digit number is simple; just multiple the first digit by 1000, add the second multiplied by 100, and so on.

But this is a one-way algorithm; you will never be able to retrieve the original four-digit number from this.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comment you are trying to do a variation on the [Caesar Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher), in which case you should be using the modulus operator (`%`) not the integer division operator (`/`).  Using integer division loses information which will prevent you from decrypting. When your digit is in {0, 1, 2} your division results in a 0.  When it is in {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, the division results in a 1.  You can't decrypt {0, 1} back into the original number without some additional information (which you have discarded).

If you want to encrypt on a digit by digit basis using the Caesar Cipher approach, you should be using [modulo arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_arithmetic) so that each digit has a unique encrypted value which can be retrieved during decryption.  If that's really what you are looking for then you should be doing something like the following to encrypt with a 7:

```
    a = (a + 7) % 10;
    b = (b + 7) % 10;
    c = (c + 7) % 10;
    d = (d + 7) % 10;
```

To decrpyt, you subtract 7, which in mod 10 arithmetic is an addition by 3, so that would be:

```
    a = (a + 3) % 10;
    b = (b + 3) % 10;
    c = (c + 3) % 10;
    d = (d + 3) % 10;
```

This of course presupposes you've properly validated your input (which isn't the case in your example above).

Answer (score 1):

This is what youd'd probably be looking for :

```
int e = (a*1000)+(b*100)+(c*10)+d;
e=e/10;
```

Comment: and if you want, you can also include the addition by 7 in this step itself!

Comment: Thanks! Also I have been told this is not encryption. I am trying to follow my book but am having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your description whether the addition should be modulo 10 or not; if so

```
((((((a % 10) * 10) + (b % 10)) * 10) + (c % 10)) * 10) + (d % 10)
```

if you don't want the modulo 10

```
(((((a * 10) + b) * 10) + c) * 10) + d
```

Answer (score 0):

Stepping aside the fact that you almost certainly want mod instead of divide (as @Andand has said), there's more than one way to turn the digits into a number!

A lot of people using interpreted languages these days would probably want to do it symbolically.  C++ can do that too, fairly neatly in fact:

```
// create a string stream that you can write to, just like
// writing to cout, except the results will be stored
// in a string

stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);

// write the digits to the string stream
ss << a << b << c << d;

cout << "The value stored as a string is " << ss.str() << endl;

// you can also read from a string stream like you're reading
// from cin.  in this case we are reading the integer value
// that we just symbolically stored as a character string

int value;
ss >> value;

cout << "The value stored as an integer is " << value << endl;
```

It won't be as efficient as multiplications in this narrow case of a 4 digit number, because of the round trip to a string and back.  But good to know the technique.  Also it's a style of coding that can be a lot easier to maintain and adapt.

You'll get stringstream if you `#include <sstream>`.